# Locate Features along routes expands to double the size of the original shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, linear-referencing

I am attempting to run the Locate Features Along Route tool (Linear Referencing) and when I run it, the output is returning almost double the amount of data points as are in the input while leaving out some of the needed. I am attempting to locate line segments on an existing road network. Both the line segments and the road network have unique ID's.
Route Identifier Field: CDS_Num
XY Tolerance: 5m
Keep only the closest route location: FIRST
Include distance field on output table: DISTANCE
keep zero length line events: ZERO
Include all fields from input: FIELDS
Use M Direction Offsetting: M_DIRECTION